# I am confusing of my C program in the case of giving a txt file to my executable program

Tags: c, file, input

I wanna count numbers of every Ascii characters from text file. So I prgrammed my C file that can read text file. Here is my C source code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
       /*c언어 소스파일을 컴파일 한 뒤 ./{실행파일명}<{넣어줄 파일명}으로 터미널에 입력하면 파일의 내용이 input으로 들어간다.
    어떠한 자료구조에 넣어주는 것이 효율적일 것인가? ==> 그냥 무식하게 하나하나 다 세는 방법도 있긴 함. 

    */
   int myAsciiList[128]={0,};//나올 때마다 더해줄 아스키 코드임.
   char gettingChar;//매번 입력받을 것을 말한다.
   scanf("%c",&gettingChar);//먼저 파일로부터 문자를 하나 입력 받는다.
   int myIndex;
   myIndex=gettingChar;
   myAsciiList[myIndex]++;
   while(1)//계속해서 입력을 받아들인다.
   {
       scanf("%c",&gettingChar);
       if(gettingChar==EOF) break;
       else{
              myIndex=gettingChar;
              myAsciiList[myIndex]++;
       }
   }
   
   return 0;
}
```

I compiled my C source code by using Visual Studio Code and made executable file. And then I gave my text file in terminal with command **"./count < input.txt"**.

But my terminal does not show me anything. Like this,
MacBookAir  ~/Desktop/2023_Algorithm/hw4   main ±  ./count < test.txt

Can you recommend me how to fix my code?

Comment: `scanf()` will not set `gettingChar` on error.  Instead if will return EOF

Comment: You program is not printing anything, right?

Comment: It's implementation defined if `char` is `signed` or `unsigned` and as you use it as an index into `myAsciiList` you assume it's positive.  You also assume it's between 0 and 127 (inclusive).

Comment: Then, you mean that I have to set my variable 'gettingChar' as unsigned?

Comment: I suggest you study my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Use symbolic constants `LEN` instead hard-coding magic values.  Especially when you need use the same variable in two places.
2. (Not fixed) Consider using a `unsigned` type (like `unsigned` or `size_t`) instead of (signed) `int` for `myAsciiList`.  This better captures the intend of positive counts.
3. It's implementation defined if `char` is `signed` or `unsigned`.  If it's signed, a negative value will cause a buffer underflow.  You also assume that the less than 128 otherwise it would cause a buffer overflow.
4. You have the same code before the loop as in it.  This is probably a mistake.  Also, before the loop you don't implement error handling which is problematic (if it worked).  It's a good idea to eliminate duplicate code.  In this case I could just remove it, other times to move duplicate code into a function and call it the function as many times as needed instead.
5. `scanf()` returns `EOF`.  It does not set the variable `gettingChar` to it.
6. You need to print something if you want output.
7. Minimize number and scope of variables whenever possible.  `char ch;` is now declared just before it's use.  `myIndex` was eliminated as it's was the same value as `ch` and below I cast it to an unsigned value when needed.
8. (Not fixed) Consider special handling of non-printable characters like space, newline or tab when you print out the result.

You probably want something along these lines:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define LEN 128

int main() {
    int myAsciiList[LEN] = {0};
    for(;;) {
        char ch;
        int rv = scanf("%c", &ch);
        if(rv == EOF)
            break;
        if(!rv) {
            printf("scanf failed\n");
            break;
        }
        if((unsigned) ch >= LEN) {
            printf("ch is too large\n");
            break;
        }
        myAsciiList[(unsigned) ch]++;
    }
    for(size_t i = 0; i < LEN; i++) {
        if(myAsciiList[i])
            printf("%c: %d\n", (char) i, myAsciiList[i]);
    }
}
```

and here is an example run with the source file as input:

```
$ ./count < count.c
        : 41

: 26
 : 38
!: 1
": 8
#: 2
%: 3
&: 1
(: 14
): 14
+: 4
,: 3
.: 1
0: 2
1: 1
2: 1
8: 1
:: 1
;: 14
<: 2
=: 6
>: 2
A: 4
E: 5
F: 1
L: 8
N: 4
O: 1
[: 4
\: 3
]: 4
_: 1
a: 10
b: 3
c: 16
d: 7
e: 11
f: 13
g: 3
h: 8
i: 37
k: 3
l: 3
m: 5
n: 18
o: 5
p: 3
r: 14
s: 15
t: 13
u: 3
v: 3
y: 4
z: 1
{: 6
}: 6
```

Comment: I totally understood your comment! Whether it is signed or unsigned affects to array indexing. Thank you very much for your help bro 

Comment: Yapp~ Have a nice day